# Data Normalization for input dataframe

Tags: machine-learning, data-analysis

Should we always normalize our input data variables when implementing any machine learning model or it's not necessary.

Comment: This is not a programming problem, do not ask off-topic questions here.

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence off-topic here; please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score -1):

The purpose of data Normalization is nothing but to *reduce gaps or differences* in the data, *reduce computational load on your device*.

---

1. If you have very good computational resources (let's say you are
   dealing with image data) then you can go ahead with out normalizing
   the data.
2. Another case would be when you are dealing with regression model
   where data of age varies from 0-100 and house price between 1000
   dollars to 900000 dollars here normalization would be useful as
   large variation might affect your model but when you normalize this
   variation would significantly reduce.

Comment: When do we use simple z normalization and when do we normalize our data using logarithm?

Comment: This answer makes no sense, normalization has nothing to do with reducing computational load.

Comment: Then why is it adviced to normalize image data? I'll tell you an incident when I normalized the image data my device trained faster then the case when I didn't normalized. I hope that clears your doubt

Comment: @UtsavSharma we normalize our data using logarithm? Could you please put more lights on it? z-score should be used when data doesnot have gaussian distribution

Comment: Kindly refrain from answering off-topic questions; please see the relevant community guidelines in [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276637/4685471)